# Node.js version and Heroku

Tags: macos, node.js

So, I got a small site started in node.js (my first one) using Express.  Pretty happy with it, until I tried to deploy to Heroku and found that I had 0.4.9 installed and they only support 0.4.7.

Is uninstalling 0.4.9 and installing 0.4.7 my only option, or is there a way to do a side-by-side on the two?

Comment: I recently discovered nvm also (https://github.com/creationix/nvm) which is probably the answer to the question as I asked it, but I marked James Ward's answer as "Answer" b/c I think his is the better overall solution to what I really wanted to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override the version of node.js and npm by customizing the Heroku build pack:
http://blog.superpat.com/2011/11/15/running-your-own-node-js-version-on-heroku/

Comment: Darn - looks like I have to go login to GoDaddy and see what's up :-(

Answer (score 2):

Actually...you do not have to remove anything.

Just ensure you are using features of node compliant with node 0.4.7 and when you make your package.json which specifies your dependencies has the correct version number or range specified.

I had a similar issue where one of our developers made is packacge and set the dependency to node 0.4.8 however it didn't require this it was just what version he was using at the time, we ended up updating his package.json to list node 0.4.7 instead and then my package which depended on his deployed to heroku just fine.

Answer (score 1):

It seems Heroku only supports 0.4.7 at the moment and even suggests to develop strictly on that version.

If you have to use heroku then you have to uninstall 0.4.9, install 0.4.7.

If you don't have to use heroku. You can always setup a VPS yourself, and you will have the freedom to install whatever version that pleases you. :D

Comment: Thanks, hadn't seen nvm.  I also recognize that I don't have to use heroku, but it's a) what I'm used to and b) the price is right for what I'm doing right now.